# Extensions-like context menu in Chrome Apps (browser wide)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have been practicing with Chrome extensions and apps and noticed `chrome.contextMenu` is not browser-wide for Chrome Apps. It only manages the context menu of the App background windows.

Is there a way to create browser-wide context menus like extensions have? If there isn't any API in Apps, how can I also include an extension with my app so that users won't need to install two different things?

Here is the project: https://github.com/metherealone/chorrent

Obviously, I only need to catch magnet links and torrent files with the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apps and extensions are separate by design. If your app needs an extension (as many desktop apps do), write one. Once you've done that, it's fairly easy for them to [communicate with messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

As for installing two things at once, your best bet is to detect the absence of the extension (perhaps by messaging and noticing that nobody responds), and recommend the installation of it. You probably shouldn't design your system so that it's broken if the user chooses to install one but not the other.

Comment: Okay, I will follow that approach then. The extension is not mandatory for the app to work but it greatly extends the usability.

Comment: Quick question: Is there a way to create a global variable space between different windows of the same app or I also need to interact with messages for that too? Accessing the main window's variables is also acceptable, can bind angular on them.

Comment: That's not a quick question. You probably meant to accept this answer, then ask a new question.